# Why does my USB card reader (Dell 2405FPW) not recognize any inserted media?

Tags: 13.10, usb, dell, card-reader

My Dell monitor (model 2405FPW) has a built in USB card reader that is recognized by Ubuntu 13.10, but any inserted SD cards do not get seen. It used to work with an older version of 32-bit Ubuntu on a different computer, but not with my new 64-bit 13.10 computer.

This shows that Linux sees the card reader:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 047: ID 0424:223a Standard Microsystems Corp. 8-in-1 Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 046: ID 0424:2504 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 045: ID 0424:2502 Standard Microsystems Corp.
```

Here's what I get in /var/log/syslog when I plug an SD card into the reader:

```
Feb  5 19:57:11 snorkack kernel: [379834.319439] usb 2-1.2.2: reset high-speed USB device number 47 using ehci-pci
Feb  5 19:57:11 snorkack kernel: [379834.463095] sd 20:0:0:3: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
```

Here is /var/log/syslog when I connect the USB cable between the monitor and the computer. There are some errors, "hub_port_status failed (err = -71)", but googling didn't it help much.

```
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.152114] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 44 using ehci-pci
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.244291] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2502
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.244296] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.244721] hub 2-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.244890] hub 2-1.2:1.0: 2 ports detected
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.347802] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.352039] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.362445] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.366669] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.377167] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.381414] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.391912] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.396153] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.406645] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.410894] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.421232] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.425477] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.435870] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.440118] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.450609] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.454860] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.465348] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.466820] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 44
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.469596] hub 2-1.2:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
Feb  5 19:46:45 snorkack kernel: [379209.469602] hub 2-1.2:1.0: activate --> -19
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379209.671687] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 45 using ehci-pci
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379209.763862] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2502
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379209.763867] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379209.764150] hub 2-1.2:1.0: USB hub found
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379209.764205] hub 2-1.2:1.0: 2 ports detected
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.035385] usb 2-1.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 46 using ehci-pci
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.127562] usb 2-1.2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2504
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.127567] usb 2-1.2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.127847] hub 2-1.2.1:1.0: USB hub found
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.127904] hub 2-1.2.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.215240] usb 2-1.2.2: new high-speed USB device number 47 using ehci-pci
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.396718] usb 2-1.2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=223a
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.396723] usb 2-1.2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.396726] usb 2-1.2.2: Product: USB2223
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.396729] usb 2-1.2.2: Manufacturer: SMSC
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.396732] usb 2-1.2.2: SerialNumber: 000223223223
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.396995] usb-storage 2-1.2.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack kernel: [379210.397199] scsi20 : usb-storage 2-1.2.2:1.0
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 47: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2"
Feb  5 19:46:46 snorkack mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 47 was not an MTP device
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.403444] scsi 20:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMSC     223 U HS-CF      3.60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.406789] scsi 20:0:0:1: Direct-Access     SMSC     223 U HS-MS      3.60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.410181] scsi 20:0:0:2: Direct-Access     SMSC     223 U HS-SM      3.60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.413131] scsi 20:0:0:3: Direct-Access     SMSC     223 U HS-SD/MMC  3.60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.413520] sd 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.413773] sd 20:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.414004] sd 20:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
Feb  5 19:46:47 snorkack kernel: [379211.414267] sd 20:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
Feb  5 19:46:48 snorkack kernel: [379211.633165] sd 20:0:0:3: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb  5 19:46:48 snorkack kernel: [379211.644220] sd 20:0:0:2: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb  5 19:46:48 snorkack kernel: [379211.651224] sd 20:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Feb  5 19:46:48 snorkack kernel: [379211.662540] sd 20:0:0:1: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hypothesis: this reader might not support SDHC (vs. SD). See [here](http://www.hjreggel.net/cardspeed/special-sd.html) for details about the dark forest of SD cards and their (buggy) readers. If your card is larger than 2Gb, then it's SDHC (and should be labeled as such).

I have the same exact hardware and same exact output. Except I got the USB port errors and the 'device offlined' error only once so far. In either case, there's no sign the card is being recognized. Tried two different SDHC cards. A different reader (Kodak) on same machine works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away when I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10.